# Reports Timeout when Opening From ASP.Net ReportViewer

Tags: sharepoint-2010, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I use this c# code for opening reports from SharePoint 2010 site and SQL Server Reporting Services 2012.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
   ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
   ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("https://site.com/_vti_bin/reportserver");
   ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "https://site.com/sites/ssrs/Reports/Report1.rdl";

   ReportViewer1.ShowParameterPrompts = false;
   ReportViewer1.ShowCredentialPrompts = false;
   IReportServerCredentials irsc = new ReportViewerCredentials("user", "pass", "domain");
   ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = irsc;
   ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
}
```

I can open the reports from SharePoint site, but when I try to open them using the above code in ASP.Net page they timeout. The code works fine since I have succeed to open reports from my test farm. In my production farm, I get the message:
**"The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly."**

The interesting thing is the reports opened twice (in two days) and when I tried to open other reports, it just failed like before. This happened when I restated IIS, but it doesn't happen again.

I have all the permissions on the server and SharePoint Farm. The report is just a page with a line on it, it doesn't even have a data source.

Comment: Wow, strange issue. If you remote desktop to the web server can you open / reach the URL's (not from asp.net) to the Reporting machine at all?

Comment: Yes, I am testing the ASP.Net application at my PC and I am able to open the reports from a web browser.

Comment: Hmm, haven't seen this before. My gut feeling would say this problem isn't specific to ssrs or sharepoint, it almost sounds more like a networking/firewall/iis/routing issue. If you don't get any answers you could try investigate that direction. Don't forget to answer your own question if you find the solution on your own! Good luck.

Comment: It is very strange, because it works when I restart the SharePoint Farm. But only for a short period of time, then it stops working.

Comment: Try 1) swithcing to http from https 2) setting ShowCredentialPrompts = true; Then report what happened.